# How to append new line text inside a log file using powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I need to pull logs from the original path in C:\ to log directory in D:\Logs but everytime the original path create new log, the script need to append new lines, not replace or rewrite the whole lines.

I already tried this but i guess this replace the whole file and I'm not sure about the Param things.

```
$SourceFolder       = "C:\ProgramData\Sophos\Sophos Anti-Virus\logs"
$DestinationFolder  = "D:\Logs\SophosAntivirus"

Function ChangeTabToSpace 
{
    Param(
        [string] $OldFile = "",
        [string] $NewFile = ""
    )
    $OldText = (Get-Content $OldFile -Raw)
    #Change all tabt \t to space 
    $NewText = ($OldText -replace "`t"," ")
    #Delete the last empty line
    if ($NewText.Length -ge 2) {
        $NewText = $NewText.Substring(0,$NewText.Length-2)
    }
    if (!(Test-path "$NewFile")) {
        New-Item -type file "$NewFile" -force | Out-Null
    }
    #Write-Output $NewText | Out-File -Encoding utf8 "$NewFile"
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($NewFile, $NewText)
}
```

Comment: Did you try [Add-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-6)?

Answer (score 2):

If its a simple text file you can use the following

`"the string you want or have" | out-file -path $path -append`

This will add the string to a new line at the end of the file.

You don't need to pipe the input in like I did... its just how I learned to use it and just kept using it.

Comment: I want to grab the log that just created on a file than append the newly add log to another file without rewriting the whole logs. Is it possible?

Comment: @Aly You can grab the contents of a file using the `get-content -path $logpath ` cmdlet. So something like `$logcontent = get-content -path $logpath` then `$logcontent | out-file -path $path -append ` should do what you want. I suggest you play around with it, but make sure to have backups of your log files incase you append something too man times and want to undo it.